# Dynamic time warp z score normalisation not working

Tags: r, time-series, normalization

I have data that looks like this [image]

A bit of background, these are soil moisture graphs of different depths. I wish to investigate how long it takes for water to drip down from one depth to another, and usually there is a bit of lag between when the data jumps upwards (when the soil gets watered) so I'm trying to calculate the lag of the blue graph compared to the red graph. Both graphs share the same x axis and start and end at the same time value.

Below is a z score normalisation attempt, but at the end of the graph, they aren't lined up very well, so this happens:

[image]

Does anyone know how to normalise this better so that the last part of the graph isn't below the other?

As well as this, it does not match well here either. 
A picture of the whole warp
[image]

At the start of the warp:

[image]